# CollectionView is overlaping the cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uicollectionview

My aim is to have a collection view at the footer of my view. The cells are filled with photos from the photo library. I don´t know why but the cells are overlaping each other. Does anybody know why? Here is the code from the ViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
     numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [self.fotoArray count];

}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"foto_cell";

    FotoCell *cell = [self.collectionView
                        dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                        forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Foto *currFoto = [self.fotoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Set the selectedFotoID 
    [CoreDataManager sharedInstance].selectedFotoId = ((Foto*)[self.fotoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).objectID;
    NSURL *u = [NSURL URLWithString:currFoto.f_path];
    [self findImage:u in: cell];


    return cell;
}

// Get Photo from Asset Library
-(void)findImage:(NSURL*)u in: (FotoCell*) cell
{

    __block FotoCell *blockCell = cell;
    //
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
        if (iref) {
            UIImage *largeimage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref];
            //[largeimage retain];
            UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref scale:0.15 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
            [blockCell.fotoThumb setImage:thumbnail];
        }
    };

    //
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    };



        NSURL *asseturl = u;
        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] autorelease];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:asseturl
                       resultBlock:resultblock
                      failureBlock:failureblock];

}
```

And here the Code from my Cell.m class:

```
@implementation FotoCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [_fotoThumb release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear about your code.But I had met this problem before.
The reason is that you add visible view(like image, UILabel,...) in cellForItemAtIndexPath:

### When collectionView sequence, all Cell views are overlap together when you scrolling.

You can try to init and imageView in you Cell, then set image name in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `itemSize` of your `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` instance.

Comment: Thanx for the answer, I love your blog btw... I have this in my ViewController and viewDidLoad Method:       [self.collectionView registerClass:[FotoCell class]
            forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];                      But it is still not working :(

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *myLayout = [[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init]autorelease];
    [myLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(48, 48)];
    [myLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:myLayout];